# Mixpanel can't log List Data types

Tags: android, react-native, mixpanel

Trying to log List Data types in Mixpanel. but it display always string types in mixpanel.

[image: React native code]

Mixpanel Event log. it displayed string types.

[image: Mixpanel screenshots]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I think it might be a mixpanel bug when a property has values of different types. I had one property which was a string but now I want to change it to a list but Mixpanel doesn't let me. It keeps displaying strings like ["option a", "option b"] instead of typecasting